# Do we need iis server installed in azure cloud to host a web app in azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

If I need to host a web app in azure cloud, do I need to install windows server and iis  in a VM or is there any other option like the web service running separately?

I have read azure app service while googled, if it's been used, Will it serve all the purpose of an iis?

Comment: There's no "right" answer to this. Maybe Web Apps (app service) works for you. Maybe you need ports other than 80/443, requiring a VM. Maybe you need to customize the environment, modify the registry, or install specific software, which can't be done in a Web App. You'll need to make this decision based on your specific requirements.

Answer (score 2):

In most scenarios you do not have to host a VM with IIS to host a web app in Azure. You can, but unless you *want* or *need* to manually manage a VM because you for instance need to install software on the server, there are simpler hosting alternatives.

Have a look at Azure [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview)

> *Azure App Service* is a service for hosting web applications, REST APIs, and mobile back ends. You can develop in your favorite language, be it .NET, .NET Core, Java, Ruby, Node.js, PHP, or Python. Applications run and scale with ease on both Windows and Linux-based environments.

**EDIT:**
As far as monitoring goes: there is a lot available to monitor the performance of an App Service. For instance:

- [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview)
- [Monitor apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor)

**EDIT2:**

> Will it serve all the purpose of an iis?

Are you looking for a specific purpose? Azure App Service brings you a LOT of possibilities. Sure, it's PaaS and therefore you're bound by the options available for the specific service. But you're also getting a lot of extra's IIS *doesn't* provide (out of the box). And when you're running a website that doesn't require you to install any COM stuff or something specific like that, there's nothing App Service doesn't provide.

Comment: Azure App Services do have some significant limitations, most important of which is the inability to monitor performance.  Might be good to mention these limitations in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but no. There is a _lot_ available to monitor the performance. One of which is [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview)

Comment: So you're saying there are no limitations on App Services versus a full server? Interesting.

Comment: @barbecue I'm not saying it doesn't have any limitations. I'm saying your statement about App Service having an inability to monitor performance is incorrect. Please see my edited answer

Comment: Gotcha. My original comment was more sweeping than I intended. I meant that you don't have the ability to monitor performance *counters* which could be a problem for some use cases. There are other limitations, like lack of RDP and limitations on installing software that could be deal breakers for some cases, it's good to include those kinds of exceptions in your answer.

Comment: in general app services are bad. slow\expensive. I'd never go for these over regular vms.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I've never had that experience with them. No offense, but when you implement with Cloud in mind, they work like a charm.

Comment: Leading off with "do **not**" is not really an objective way to answer the OP's question (a question that really has no objective answer anyway). There are several reasons where a VM might be a good choice over Web Apps: when sandbox restrictions block certain software installs, needing ports other than 80/443, needing further control of CPU/RAM, wanting to work with Azure Files as a mounted disk, etc.

Comment: True. I've updated my answer to be a bit more objective.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the website is available to the entire internet? Is there a way to allow only my company staff to access the website? For example: an intranet site.

Comment: @variable It does. Fortunately, you can [Set up Azure App Service access restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).